# In Java, how do I read the content line by line of another console application that's running?

Tags: java, console, streaming, output

I have a .exe program called Blockland.exe running. It uses a game engine called TorqueScript but it is a console application that I think uses c++ to make it an application. People have made programs which stream the console of blockland.exe before but are nowhere to be found.

In general, how would you get the output of another running console application? Once I get the lines I know how to do what I need to do with it, but how would I get the output of the console application using Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` in java provides a way to execute an external OS command and pipe input and read output from the external command. Here is a sample which does that:

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("/path/to/Blockland.exe");
command.add("Other arguments");
ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process proc = procBuilder.start();

ProcessOutputReader outputReader =
    new ProcessOutputReader(proc.getInputStream());
ProcessOutputReader errorReader =
    new ProcessOutputReader(proc.getErrorStream());

Thread out = new Thread(outputReader);
out.start();

Thread error = new Thread(errorReader);
error.start();

proc.waitFor();
```

Where `ProcessOutputReader` is a class that implements `Runnable`. It starts reading from the stream provided in constructor until the end-of-file occurs in the stream. This is the thread that can read the output and process it. Note that you must process the streams using separate threads, since the buffer given by java/OS for the child processes are limited. If the child processes start putting too much data in either stream (error/output) and the buffer becomes full, it'll hang.

For example it may look like (implementation is not complete):

```
public class ProcessOutputReader
{
    public void run()
    { 
        int ch;

        try
        { 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpStream));
            // The output can be of any size. So read in chunks
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                // handle line
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handle exceptions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you say //handle the output, I was wondering how you could convert those number characters into readable strings, line by line

Comment: If you want to read line by line, you can use a `BufferedInputStream`. Edited my answer to reflect this.